# Explain this javascript code

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a question regarding variable assignment

```
var foo = {n: 1};

foo.x = foo = {n: 2};

console.log(foo.x) // undefined
```

Why `foo.x` is `undefined` ?

Comment: if you assign 5 to x and y why will it be three

Comment: sorry, @RiteshK i removed that

Comment: If foo is an object, and foo.x is a reference to foo... so foo === foo.x === foo.x.x... You just can't do that ^^

Comment: It has to do with variable declaration

Comment: Update.. I have wrong. If you do `foo = {a:1}` and after `foo.x = foo` you got : `foo === {a:1, x:[Circular]}`. So your code should work

Comment: The `foo` part of `foo.x` gets evaluated *before anything else* to refer to the original object, so you're assigning to the `x` property of the original `var foo` object and then updating that variable to point to a new object.

Comment: you can do foo_x= foo =  {n: 2};

Comment: RiteshK it's not the question. you can do it on 2 lines instead of one and it's working fine

Comment: ...if you put `var bar = foo` between those two lines, you'll see that `bar`, which references the old object, gets the `x` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `=` assignment operator is right-associative, meaning that a chain of assignments is evaluated right to left. That is, the language treats this

```
x = y = x+2;
```

as if it were written

```
x = (y = x+2);
```

So first `y` is assigned the result of the addition (`5`), and then `x` is assigned the value of that assignment, which is also `5`.

The first example in your question is the same story, but things are a little more complicated:

```
foo.x = foo = { n: 2 };
```

The first assignment that's made is to `foo`, of that object literal. However, *before* that point, the language will have determined the reference value of `foo.x`, which is a reference to a (not-yet existing) property on the *original* `foo` object. Thus, when the value of the right-hand assignment is made to that property, it does work, but the property is set on the old object, not the new one!

Let's change the example:

```
var foo = {n: 1}, foo2 = foo;

foo.x = foo = {n: 2};

console.log(foo2.x); // { n: 2 }
```

That version preserves another reference to the original value of `foo` in the variable `foo2`. Even though `foo` is overwritten in the double assignment, `foo2` will continue to refer to the original `foo`.

Comment: This question has been removed

Comment: @RiteshK yes - see the answer update, and I'm adding an example

Comment: This is why `foo.x = foo = {a:1};` is different to `foo = {a:1}; foo.x = foo;`. In the first case the reference isn't create, but on second yes.

Comment: @Pointy
is foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
breaks down to 
foo.x = {n: 2};
foo = {n: 2};
?